# Create sheets with Excel VBA based on values in other column

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have the following VBA code to create sheets from a list 'Analysepakket' with range D19:D33 as shown in picture.
How do I alter my VBA code so it only makes new sheets where the value 'J' or 'j' is found in the other column?

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromList()

Dim ws As Worksheet, Ct As Long, c As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Opdrachtregistratie")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In Sheets("Laboratorium").Range("D19:D33")
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        ws.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(Left(c.Value, 30), "/", "-")
        Ct = Ct + 1
    End If
Range("C30").Value = c.Value
Next c
If Ct > 0 Then
    MsgBox Ct & " new sheets created from list"
Else
    MsgBox "No names on list"
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `If c.Value <> "" And UCase(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "J" Then`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I can confirm that your solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value of a cell relative to another cell with the `Offset` method. This method get 2 parameters, the first is the number of rows, the second the number of columns. Both parameter can be 0 (stay on the same row resp. column) and negative (go to the top resp. to the left).

To read the cell left to another cell, you can use `Offset(0, -1)` - the 0 says you want to read the same row, the -1 is the column at the left.

Simply change your If-condition to

```
If c.Value <> "" And UCase(c.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "J" Then
```

Comment: That solution works. I was overcomplicating things with a xlookup function. Thanks for your simple and elegant solution.